# Solr parameter substitute

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud

I have URL in solr as :

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/demo7/select?q=*:*&fq=o_photo_id:2014111713 &apps_name:'DS'&wt=xml.
```

I have two parameters `o_photo_id` and `apps_name`.

I need to add extra field `member_id` which is not in `data configuration` while integration.

How to add the extra parameter?

Comment: how are you building this URL...? Can you provide more inputs on the same?

Comment: http://localhost:8983/solr/demo7/select?q=*:*&fq=o_photo_id:2014111713%20&apps_name:%27DS%27&wt=xml. I'm my integrated Postgresql with Solr and denormalize the mulitple tables. I need to pass three parameters 1)apps_name 2) photo_id 3) member_id. I have one output parameter o_photo_id based on it displaying data and i need to add two fields in url as member_id and apps_name. Is it possbile to pass in solr url.

Comment: are these fields 'member_id' and 'apps_name' in your schema.xml? are they indexed..? i.e required=true...?

Comment: No sir..It is input parameters in postgresql stored procedure

Comment: How to pass postgresql stored procedure input parameter in solr url..

Comment: OK...Now we got your question...

Comment: It works if the stored procedure contains a simple SELECT query...

Comment: are you using DataImportHandler...? if yes then...DataImportHandler does not directly support calling regular stored procedures..

Comment: Yes, I'm using dataimporthandler. But, in postgresql stored procedure we have  input parameters(apps_name, photo_id, member_id) i need to pass same input parameters in solr url but it is not defined in schema.xml.

Comment: DataImportHandler does not directly support calling regular stored procedures.....Check if you can convert the stored procedure into select query...the select query could solve your problem...

Comment: Yes sir.I convert into select statement.But unable to pass input parameters. Please provide your email id. I will forward my query. Thanks in advance.

Comment: bashettiabhijit@rediffmail.com

Comment: sir..i forward mail. Please look into it.Please help me.

Comment: please check this example https://javatoj2ee.wordpress.com/2012/08/30/how-to-call-stored-procedure-from-solr//

Comment: sir longback i done like that way but they are saying again it hit db and display the data. It takes time to display data we need to display in solr same like postgresql stored procedure.

Comment: I tried ...but did not succeed...

Comment: I forward one mail below i added data-config.xml for stored procedure. It will helpful to you. Thanks